# Dynamically change the background color of a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing

I want to change cell background color of JTable and want to fetch data from MySQL database.

I am using a data table in MySQL which has a status field. If the status is 1 then cell background color should be red and if the status is 0 then it should change to red.

Comment: so basically you want it to be red all the time?

Comment: Hi There! Generally speaking, for people to properly answer your question in a way that makes sense in the context of your application, we need to see some relevant code snippets from your code, in it's current form we can't really tell you much about how to fix this issue aside from "use an if statement" or something silly like that.

Comment: So basicly you want us to search. There is good tutorial about how to improve the design of JTable. This might be a good start, then if this doesn't work, come back with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This is the code which I have used to change jtable cell background color dynamically
[green color indicates empty(free) cell and red color indicates occupied cells][1]
 int row, col, row1, column;
    TableCellRenderer renderer;
    private static final int STATUS_COL = 1;
String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/your_database";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        Statement stmt = null;
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
            stmt = connect.createStatement();
            String sql = "your query";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
            Object[][] data = new Object[10][2];
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 int rowCnt = 0;
              try{

       rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
       if(rs.last()){
           rowCnt = rs.getRow();
       } 
    } catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("Error getting row count");
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

            int nCol = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<>();
String[] row = new String[nCol];
for(int l=1; l<rowCnt; l++)
{
    for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= nCol; iCol++) {
                    Object obj = rs.getObject(iCol);
                    row[iCol - 1] = (obj == null) ? null : obj.toString();
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new EntryCellRender());
 }
                table.add(row);
}
 } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
public class EntryCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private final Color alt2 = Color.RED;
    private final Color alt1 = Color.GREEN;
    private final Color invalidStatus = Color.RED;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component cr = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
if ("".equals(table.getValueAt(row, col))) {
             setBackground(alt1);
           } else {
               setBackground(alt2);
           }

        return cr;
    }

    private Color colorAlternator(int row) {
        if ((row % 2) == 0) {
            return alt1;
        } else {
            return alt2;
        }
    }
}   

    enter code here

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi4LF.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

id suggest a custom cell renderer to achieve what you want to.

```
public class CellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (column == /*your column number goes here*/) {
            this.setValue(table.getValueAt(row, column));
            this.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

before you set the color, you can check the value if its 0 or 1 and then change the color if it is what you want

How I created and filled/refilled a JTable with data from a database:

Table:

```
private void createTable(Container pane) {
    Object[] namen = { "Datum", "Kategorie", "Essen", "Preise Intern", "Preise Extern" };
    model = new DefaultTableModel(namen, 0);
    table = new JTable(model) {

        public boolean isCellEditable(int x, int y) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(1000, 500);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(minimumSize);
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);

    sorter.setComparator(3, Sorter.getComparator());
    sorter.setComparator(4, Sorter.getComparator());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer()); //custom cell renderer
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer()); //custom cell renderer

    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
}
```

and how i filled it:

```
void refreshTableContent(Vector<Gericht> v) {
    for (int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        model.removeRow(i);
    }
    fillTable(v);
}

void fillTable(Vector<Gericht> v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        Gericht g = v.get(i);
        Vector<Object> vhelp = new Vector<>();
        vhelp.add(df.format(g.getDate()));
        vhelp.add(g.getClassification());
        vhelp.add(g.getName());
        vhelp.add(g.getPreisIntern());
        vhelp.add(g.getPreisExtern());
        model.addRow(vhelp);
    }
}
```

`model` is a `DefaultTableModel` on which you add and delete data. at every refill, i first delete all rows and then add them new. this is probably not the best solution but it works

the model is a meal in this case which has several fields. so i created a vector of my own object and then created a helping vector and stored the values of one meal in it. then i added the vector as row to the JTable and the next meal was stored in the helping vector.

I hope you can understand what i did here

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply.

Comment: But I am not getting how to connect to database and fetch values  in JTable with dynamically background color change of the cell.

Comment: Even I want to divide data of a table in slots of 40 rows and remaining in next column. Like that I have 2000 rows and want to display in 40 rows and 50 columns format.

Comment: can you give an example on how you want the table to look like? you will have to create the table first and then fill it with the data you fetched from the database

Comment: Thanks xtremebaumer for your reply and concern.

Comment: I have around 200 entries / records in my table and the table has 4 columns C_No, R_no, item_code and status.  C_no and R_no will have fixed values where item_code and status gets updated on the basis of operation. If I dispose an Item from machine that time Item_code will get updated to "" (blank cell) and status will be replaced with 0. Now I want to make cell background color as red where Item_code is present and status = 1, & where Item_code = " " and status = 0 there I want cell background color as green, which shows empty location.

Comment: Basically its a Dispensing machine and I want to display live status of the machine.

Comment: Actually comment box is not allowing me to attach image of the sample output.

Comment: so you basically only fetch c_no and r_no from the database and then do some operation on it to calculate item_code and status? in which way do you dispose an item (database or JTable)? basically you have to refill the JTable every time, you change a value and then the cellrenderer does his work

Comment: Yes, you are right. Can you tell me how to refill JTable every time with cellrenderer option. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: can it happen that you have item_code="" and status=1?

Comment: Thanks XtremeBaumer. Its working fine but I am not getting how to fetch it from database and change cell background color of jtable.

Comment: background of whole JTable? have a look at mysql connector in java to access your database

Answer (score -1):

As *XtremeBaumer* suggests, a custom cell renderer is a standard way to achieve what you want. Just remember that only one (1) instance of the cell renderer class is created and is used to render all the JTable cells.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi guys!... Finally I could manage to complete my assignment.